# I receive "Error 3251" retrieving table keys in Access 2013 (ADO VBA) with this piece of code

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I'm trying to list a local database relationships with ADO with code.

Code works with SQL Server connection, but not with CurrentProject connection. Code is below.

Any idea?

```
Sub SeeRelationshipsADO()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

    Dim catADOX As New ADOX.Catalog 'El catálogo ADOX
    Dim tblADOX As ADOX.Table       'Tabla ADOX
    Dim KeyADOX As ADOX.key         'Clave ADOX

    Dim strRIName As String

    Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

        'Seteo el catálogo
        Set catADOX.ActiveConnection = conn

        Set tblADOX = catADOX.Tables("ST_JLE_Materiales")

            For Each KeyADOX In tblADOX.Keys

            'Here returns error 3251

            Next KeyADOX

    Set KeyADOX = Nothing
    Set tblADOX = Nothing
    Set catADOX = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If `Set catADOX.ActiveConnection = conn` doesn't raise error, then if table doesn't have keys, then the loop will be skipped. There's something you didn't show us. Which line namely is highlighted?

Comment: Edited for clarity, appoints only a table, wich has three relations. Same problem in:
 
-

For Each KeyADOX In tblADOX.Keys

Comment: Once again: which line is highlighted by debugger?

Comment: For Each KeyADOX In tblADOX.Keys is highlighted. Object or provider can't execute requested operation

Comment: I have created sample database and table with PK initially. Then I removed PK. There were no errors.

Comment: What namely does error say?

Comment: Error number 3251

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205769/discussion-between-johnyl-and-javier).

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

Thanks to JohnyL

It's not possible to do the matter with linked tables and local tables at once